# Как зашифровать ссылку в исходном коде страницы?

Tags: jquery, html, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Как зашифровать ссылку в исходном коде странице, чтобы при просмотре исходного кода страницы ссылка не была видна в исходном коде странице?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();var flashInstalled = false;if (typeof(navigator.plugins)!="undefined"&&typeof(navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"])=="object"){ flashInstalled = true;} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined") {try {if (new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")) {flashInstalled = true;}} catch(e) {};};
            var flashvars = {"m":"video","file":"http://10.60.1.116/wordpress/output/stream/media.php?vname=01_metka_video"};

               if(ua.indexOf("iphone") != -1 || ua.indexOf("ipad") != -1 || (ua.indexOf("android") != -1 && !flashInstalled)){
               flashvars["uid"]="videoplayer119";
               flashvars["st"]="uppodvideo";
               var player = new Uppod(flashvars);
               }else{
                   var params = {allowFullScreen:"true", allowScriptAccess:"always",id:"videoplayer119",bgcolor:"#ffffff"};
                   new swfobject.embedSWF("http://10.60.1.116/wordpress/player/uppod.swf", "videoplayer119", "500", "375", "10.0.0.0", false, flashvars, params);
               }
</script>
```

Как скрыть ссылку `http://10.60.1.116/wordpress/output/stream/media.php?vname=01_metka_video` в данном случае?

Comment: Глупая идея, всё равно эта ссылка будет видна в загруженных ресурсах как есть.

Comment: Даже если это глупая идея, мне все равно нужно это реализовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как?

Comment: Да пожалуйста: www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx

Comment: @demonicq2014, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это в общем-то довольно несложно сделать, но вопрос тут тогда становится иной: сколько людей не догадаются о наличии в коде зашифрованной ссылки. А ответ тут простой: подавляющее меньшинство, среди которых преимущественно компьютерно безграмотные люди. Ведь для непосредственного использования ссылки вам ее по-любому придется расшифровывать (чем бы вы там ее ни шифровали)  для получения контента, который она несет. В этом случае, как уже вам сказали выше, даже с исходным кодом не придется иметь дела - достаточно будет заглянуть в сетевой стек, расположенный во многих современных браузерах и узнать тем самым обо всем, что вы так пытались скрыть.

Если же вы не планируете загружать по "секретной" ссылке никакого контента, то можно зашифровать её с помощью любого двунаправленного алгоритма шифрования (который позволяет производить расшифровку),  например, base64; можете хоть свой придумать. Но человек знающий все равно рано или поздно выяснит алгоритм шифрования или просто в определенном месте кода JS произведет инжект своего кода, похожего на этот:

```
...
var myEncryptedUrl = "gerpiuiwr3284902%&*8^%";
...
var myDecryptedUrl = decryptMySuperSecretUrl(myEncryptedUrl);
alert(myDecryptedUrl)
...
```

**P.S.**

А вообще можете использовать открытый URL, на котором, например, будет располагаться скрипт, вытягивающий контент с секретного URL и отдающий его клиенту. Вот в таком случае поиск достоверного URL действительно в разы усложняется.

**Обновление**

[[@demonicq2014](/users/25564/demonicq2014)](/users/25564/demonicq2014), зависит все же от характера требуемого шифрования. По сути, можете просто использовать так называемый "алгоритм Цезаря", сдвигая посимвольно номера кодов символов.

---

По поводу использования Base64 в JavaScript вот:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Не могу сказать наверняка, кроссбраузерно ли это... в любом случае исследуйте.

Comment: А можно пример, как зашифровать ссылку в данном случае хотя бы через base64, меня простая защита интересует не от хакеров.

Comment: > Но человек знающий все равно рано или поздно выяснит алгоритм шифрования.

Или даже просто воспользуется функционалом автора для расшифровки, что окончательно сводит разработку такого решения в глубокую печаль.

Comment: Это я все знаю, это понятно, но мне нужно сделать простую защиту для дураков

Comment: @demonicq2014, обновил ответ.

Comment: > А вообще можете использовать открытый URL, на котором, например, будет располагаться скрипт, вытягивающий контент с секретного URL и отдающий его клиенту -- пожалуй лучший ответ.  Еще можно генерировать эту линку в зависимости от id сессии, user-agenta, IP, реферера и каких-либо других параметров, так что одна линка будет действительна только для одного клиента.